# Android TV layout Eligibility Issue on Play store

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, android-tv

I'm trying to make my app available on the play store for TVs, but google is rejecting it claiming vertical letterboxing, but I don't know what that is, and in the emulator, all screens work fine

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKeWl.png)

[Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdOvX.png)

[Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HFKQ.png)

[Screen 3, its a webview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8Bys.png)

[Preload Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iq8nc.png)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/enhanced-letterboxing

Answer (score 0):

Please check your AndroidManifest.xml file.

1 Make sure all your activities/Fragments are in landscape mode(if
declared explicitly).

2 It is strongly recommended to use a Leanback theme:

```
<activity
  android:name="com.example.android.TvActivity"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback">
```

3 Your Activities should have a NoTitleBar theme:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.android.TvActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

4 Avoid screen elements being clipped due to overscan and by incorporating a 10%
margin on all sides of your layout. This translates into a 48dp margin on the left
and right edges and a 27dp margin on the top and bottom of your base layouts for
activities. The following example layout demonstrates how to set these margins in
the root layout for a TV app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/base_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="27dp" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm using react native, I can't use two activities to render the leanback theme.

I have two types of screens in react, one for cell phones and smartphones, and one dedicated to TVs.

When the app opens, react native checks the device type and redirects to the corresponding screen